# What do these Clementine extras do? What is "Rain" and "Make it so!"?

Tags: clementine

Using the Clementine music player (1.4 rc2) on Debian 11, there is a menu named "Extras".

The two choices "Rain" and "Make it so!" can each be checked, but they don't seem to do anything (either visually, or auditorially... if that is a word now).

Can anyone provide a picture, or maybe a short explanation of what should be seen on screen when these are selected?

---

<sub>*Yes, a quick internet search reveals that I have shamelessly copied from this question here. That is because the answer from this person says nothing. There are no words there: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/clementine-player/Clementine/6729/653499524*</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you linked is also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/6729) with some useful answers. These options should play some background noises. Rain is surprisingly rain sound and it should play an [MP3 file](http://data.clementine-player.org/rainymood) from Clementine website, but the [link doesn't work](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/6611). "Make it so" should be white noise that should sound like [background noise on Enterprise](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/2527). This one actually works for me with 1.4rc2, it's just very quiet.